# Odd initial condition makes heat equation odd

Tags: integration, solution-verification, heat-equation, even-and-odd-functions

Is my proof correct for saying that if the diffusion equation has an odd initial condition then the diffusion equation must be odd.
I have this:
$$\partial_{t} u - \partial_{xx} u = 0\\
u(x,0) = f(x)\\
So: u(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x-y,t)f(y)dy\\
u(-x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-(-x+y)^2}{4t}}(-f(-y))dy\\
\text{let  } z = -y \text{ and } dz = -dy\\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}e^{\frac{-(x-z)^2}{4t}}(f(z))dz\\
= \frac{-1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-(x-z)^2}{4t}}(f(z))dz\\
= -u(x,t)$$